# Performing a RenderTransform immediately after adding to a Grid is causing problems because elements have not been added to the VisualTree

Tags: c#, wpf, expression-blend

All I want to do is add my UserControl at a specific point on the Grid.
Now I can do this using a RenderTransform after adding to the Gird, but I don't think they have been added to the VisualTree when this happens.

Is there a way to wait for the UI thread to complete before doing my Transform? Any way to add an item to the grid using pixels? i.e. 40px from the left and 40px from the top?

The code I am using is as follows....

```
grid.Children.Add(temp);
TranslateTransform transform = new TranslateTransform(-oldPosition.X+temp.posx, -oldPosition.Y+temp.posy);              
temp.RenderTransform = transform;
```

oldPosition is where it gets added to the gird in the first place, a Point.
temp.posx and temp.posy are the x and y coordinates where I would like the UserControl to be.

Also note that I do not have any rows and columns set up on the grid, the reason for using the grid is so I can have the application maximised and the grid will fill the whole screen, a Canvas does not seem to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do:

```
grid.Children.Add(temp);
Grid.SetColumn(textBlock, Y);
Grid.SetRow(textBlock, X);
```

Comment: I have tried that exact code, but the Controls still end up right in the middle of the screen. I think it's because I have not set up any rows or columns for the grid, is there a way to do this so I can still have a full screen application? Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

I believe `UpdateLayout` will do it:

```
grid.Children.Add(temp);
grid.UpdateLayout();
TranslateTransform transform = new TranslateTransform(-oldPosition.X+temp.posx, -oldPosition.Y+temp.posy);
temp.RenderTransform = transform;
```

Comment: That has helped the situation! :) I am now able to use just one button to add Controls and position them. I take it there is not a way to call this method from the Constructor, so that I don't have to press a button at all? So it will add and position on start up. Thank you!